# can i say javax.servlet.servlet as a marker interface as it provides some special effect?

Tags: java

we know that if my class is implementing some marker interface then my object is treated as a special object.

By taking it into the consideration if my class implements `javax.servlet.Servlet` interface then my class object treated as a special object ( or it added a special functionality ) 
then can we say `javax.servlet.Servlet` as marker interface or not with reason?

Answer (score 1):

No you cant say javax.servlet.Servlet as Marker Interface. It has defined methods like destroy ,getServletConfig() etc refer http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html . Marker interface has no methods like Serializable Refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html and by the way there in no term defined by Java as Marker Interface.

Comment: how do u know marker interface is not expected to have any method ?is it written in java api or it is a specification that we have to follow?

Answer (score 1):

A marker interface is not expected to have any method declaration in it. javax.servlet.Servlet contains several methods and therefore, it cannot be termed as a marker interface.

Comment: how do u know marker  interface is not expected to have any method ?is it written in java api or it is a specification that we have to follow?

Comment: Marker interfaces are actually a design (anti-)pattern but and should be replaced with annotations.

Comment: if it is a design pattern can we make our own marker interface?if we are writing a interface having no fields can we call it as amarker interface

Comment: yes @jyotisman. But my next question would be why marker interface why not have custom annotation then?

Comment: i have not been worked with @annotation ?  could u give me a example of customize annotation?